# Having an entire project reviewed

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, code-length, projects

I have a small project I'm working on in an area I'm not comfortable with (web development). I would like someone to review my code. I can try to split it up, but I would prefer if someone looked at the project as a whole. It doesn't look like this is the right place. Can someone refer me to where I can go to do this? I've been to "rent a coder" sites, but I'm not sure how I can get someone who knows what they are doing.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the project as a whole"? Is it the project structure, the project code, or reviewing the project from a "customer" point of view?

Comment: I mean the project structure and code, including the UI code (not the "look" of the page though).

Comment: In that case, it sounds perfectly on-topic.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you want the **code** to get reviewed. So if you can post an understandable question and explain your project and include the code within the 65536 character limit for posts, then it sounds perfectly on topic for me.  (The usual Stack Exchange limit is 30 000 bytes; Code Review allows 65536 bytes as of 2015-08-15.)

Answer (score 4):

Formulate a question based on the most dubious part of the code.  (Bad code is OK, as long as it meets our minimum standard that it works as intended.)  When posting the question, embed the excerpt being discussed in the question itself, but also link to the entire codebase, on GitHub, for example.  Reviewers *can* draw on the entire repository for context; they *may* make remarks about the rest of the project, but are not obligated to.  Gauge the reaction, and post further questions with excerpts from the rest of the codebase as appropriate.